# Getting error while installing memsql python library "_mysql.c:44:10: fatal error: 'my_config.h' file not found" on MAC OSx

Tags: python-2.7, singlestore

When am trying to install the memsql python library getting below error

I have tried the below options already:
sudo pip install memsql

sudo pip install memsql --global-option=build_ext --global-option="-I/usr/local/opt/openssl/include" --global-option="-L/usr/local/opt/openssl/lib"

```
Installing collected packages: MySQL-python, memsql
  Running setup.py install for MySQL-python ... error
    Complete output from command /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Resources/Python.app/Contents/MacOS/Python -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/private/tmp/pip-install-JDxMyP/MySQL-python/setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" build_ext -I/usr/local/opt/openssl/include -L/usr/local/opt/openssl/lib install --record /private/tmp/pip-record-azfFw0/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile:
    running build_ext
    building '_mysql' extension
    creating build
    creating build/temp.macosx-10.14-intel-2.7
    cc -fno-strict-aliasing -fno-common -dynamic -g -Os -pipe -fno-common -fno-strict-aliasing -fwrapv -DENABLE_DTRACE -DMACOSX -DNDEBUG -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -Wshorten-64-to-32 -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -Os -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -DENABLE_DTRACE -arch i386 -arch x86_64 -pipe -Dversion_info=(1,2,5,'final',1) -D__version__=1.2.5 -I/usr/local/Cellar/mysql/8.0.15/include/mysql -I/usr/local/opt/openssl/include -I/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/include/python2.7 -c _mysql.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.14-intel-2.7/_mysql.o
    _mysql.c:44:10: fatal error: 'my_config.h' file not found
    #include "my_config.h"
             ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
    1 error generated.
    error: command 'cc' failed with exit status 1}
```

Answer (score 1):

In order to install `memsql-python` you need to ensure that you have the dependencies already available.  Specifically, the dependency that seems to be missing from your environment is `libmysqlclient-dev` or an equivalent package.

Note - you are overriding the include paths to point at your openssl installation which may be causing this issue due to how the compiler is searching for development headers.

According to the project's readme, use the following steps to get started quickly on Ubuntu:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install -y mysql-client python-dev libmysqlclient-dev python-pip
sudo pip install memsql
```

Use the following steps to get started with RHEL based distributions such as Amazon Linux or Centos:

```
sudo yum update
sudo yum install -y gcc mysql-devel
sudo pip install memsql
```

-- edit to address question regarding installation on Mac OSX
On a Mac it appears that you can install the `mysql-client` package from brew which in theory should provide the libmysqlclient-dev package.  Once available try installing the memsql-python package without overriding linker flags since memsql-python should build fine without openssl.  If you need openssl support then you will need to ensure that both the openssl and libmysqlclient-dev shared objects are available to the linker at compilation time.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but am looking for the solution for MAC OS

Answer (score 0):

This procedure worked for me:

```
brew remove mysql
brew install mysql@5.7
brew link --force mysql@5.7
```

I read a post and adjusted the procedure to link things in the /usr/local/bin instead of adding a new route to the PATH variable.
Reference: [MacOS: "pip install MySQL-python" returning an error: "_mysql.c:44:10: fatal error: 'my_config.h' file not found"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63990900/macos-pip-install-mysql-python-returning-an-error-mysql-c4410-fatal-err)